# Angular - Role Based Authorization with Okta

Tags: angular, okta

I was able to implement the Authentication in my Angular App using okta/okta-angular-npm package. Now we need to implement role based Authorization. We have role groups created but how can we implement it in a Angular Code.

Answer (score 0):

I Believe you have an idea of `AuthGuard`, & also I am assuming that in User Model you have a parameter of `UserRole`,

Within your AuthGuard try to check user role, Please have look on below code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { OktaAuthService } from './app.service';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class OktaAuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private okta: OktaAuthService, private router: Router) {}

  async canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    const authenticated = await this.okta.isAuthenticated();
    if (authenticated) {
       
       const user = await this.okta.getUser();
       if(user.role == "YOUR_EXPECTED_ROLE") {
          return true;
       }
       
    }

    // Redirect to login flow.
    this.okta.login(state.url);
    return false;
  }
}
```

If you check above inside the first If Condition I am getting the user, within that verifying the user role, In this way you can perform role based authentication

It's not a proper solution, but whatever you are trying to achieve, this approach may help you.

Comment: Hi Suneel , i tried getting the user and got all of the info except role. Do i need to configure anything in my Okta Application to get the role. I have already created groups in Okta.

Comment: As you mentioned that you have created role groups, can you get `user group info` with user info?

Comment: No i am not able to get user group info. i am getting name,sub,email,family_name etc...Bu t i am not getting role.

Comment: maybe this will help? https://devforum.okta.com/t/how-to-get-value-of-groups-claim-in-angular-spa/7592